# Where can I find the source code for `uptime`?

Tags: fedora, source, uptime

I am learning Python. Till now I've been doing only basic Python coding. A day ago, I checked python implementation of `tree` command. Suddenly I thought of creating a Python clone for `uptime`. I don't have any clue about which language it is implemented in and what would be the complexity involved in cloning it.

But I couldn't find its source code. I am using Fedora 14. kernel-devel package is installed. I did `whereis uptime` but the resulting `/usr/bin/uptime` file shows weird symbols when opened using vim. Googling for its source code couldn't yield desired results either. Where can I find its source code?

Comment: Rather than (or in addition to) opening files with vim to see what they're made of, try `file /usr/bin/uptime`. The file command uses a series of semi-magical heuristics to guess as to the contents of the file — in this case, an ELF-format binary executable.

Comment: A debugging tool I like is `strace`.  It will show all the syscalls your application makes.  If you run `strace uptime` it would show (after loading) open calls on /proc/uptime and /proc/loadavg. Though it doesn't show everything, it's sometimes a decent start on reverse engineering

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uptime is part of the 'procps' package, the upstream source is at http://procps.sourceforge.net/  (Not a fedora user, so not sure where to find their .src.rpm).

To answer the question you didn't ask, however; take a look in /proc/uptime
The first number is seconds since boot.  You should be able to turn that into something usable fairly easily :)

Comment: Thanks. Got the code. I did checkout /proc/uptime before posting here. That was the last option I was gonna use.

Comment: Just looked at the source, the code just reads the uptime in from /proc/uptime.  Check the .../proc/sysinfo.c in the procps source, for the uptime() function: http://gitorious.org/procps/procps/blobs/master/proc/sysinfo.c#line75

Answer (score 9):

In general, on a RPM-based distribution like Fedora, you can find the name of the package which provides a given command with `rpm -qf /path/to/command`. Like this:

```
$ rpm -qf $( which uptime )
procps-3.2.8-18.20110302git.fc16.x86_64
```

You can then download the source RPM with `yumdownloader --source procps`. (yumdownloader comes from the `yum-utils` package, if you don't have that installed already.) Once you have the src.rpm, you can unpack it with either `rpm -i` or with `rpm2cpio`.

Alternately, in many cases you can query the RPM package for the project URL, which may helpfully point you to the upstream source:

```
$ rpm -qi procps|grep ^URL
URL         : http://gitorious.org/procps
```

And, cool, there's the code conveniently browsable online. If you follow through it, basically all it does is read `/proc/uptime` and print it prettily.